# Renderização com v-for

Tags: javascript, html, json, vue.js

Tenho esse código html
(tenho uma tag script no head que instancia o vue já)

```
<table class="table-striped" id="productsTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nome</th>
      <th>Preço</th>
      <th>Descrição</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="product in products">
      <td>
        {{ product.name }}
      </td>
      <td>
        {{ product.value }}
      </td>
      <td>
        {{ product.description }}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script>
    var read = require('read-file-utf8');
    var loki = require('lokijs');
    var db = new loki('db.json');
    var data = read(__dirname + "/db.json");
    db.loadJSON(data);
    var products = db.getCollection('products');
    new Vue({
        el: 'body',
        data: {
            products: []
        },
        ready: () => {
            this.products = products.data;
        }
    });
    require('./render.js');
</script>
```

alguem sabe me dizer porque nao funciona??

Answer (score 0):

Duas coisas:

**Sobre ler o JSON:**

Esse código para ler o ficheiro é código de servidor, não vai funcionar no browser. O  `read-file-utf8` é um atalho para o `fs.readFile` do Node.js e isso não funciona no browser. Curiosamente, se funcionasse mais valia teres `products: products.data` dentro do objeto `data` pois esses dados já estariam lidos...

**Sobre como carregar dados na instância do Vue:**

O Vue não tem `ready`, usa `created` (um dos primeiros [*hooks*](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks) a ser chamado) ou `mounted` que é chamado quando o componente é adicionado ao DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Falta a Tag template

```
<template>
<table class="table-striped" id="productsTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nome</th>
      <th>Preço</th>
      <th>Descrição</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="product in products">
      <td>
        {{ product.name }}
      </td>
      <td>
        {{ product.value }}
      </td>
      <td>
        {{ product.description }}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</template>
```